# How to use ssh command, using execlp()?

Tags: c, linux

I want to run the following code, but its not working:

```
int main ()
{
     execlp("ssh user@192.168.170.155", "ssh user@192.168.170.155", NULL);
     return 0;
}
```

But if I replace ssh with any other command(say ls) its working fine.

Thanks,
Yuvi

Comment: "Not working" is not a built-in C error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read the man page of [execlp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp)?

You probably want

```
int main() {
  execlp("ssh", "ssh", "user@192.168.170.155", NULL);
  perror("execlp ssh");
  return 1; // failing exit code if execlp failed.
}
```

The `execlp` could fail (e.g. if `ssh` is not in your `$PATH`)

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass it multiple commands and be done with it. You also can't pass it commands and arguments in the same string. The best you can do:

```
execlp("ssh", "ssh", "user@192.168.170.155", NULL);
```

Comment: There is an argv[0] missing here, should be `"ssh"` given twice.